# What was the intuition behind the Weierstrass substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was curious about how we let $t = \tan(x/2)$ when we perform this technique. Correct me if I am wrong, but is the purpose of letting $t = \tan(x/2)$ is simply just to eliminate the square roots?

Comment: Perhaps if you use it in an example, the process can be better understood.

Comment: No, it is used to convert trigonometric functions to rational functions without loss of generality.

Comment: IMHO this question is not very well written. One possible reason is: that "many know what this sobsititution is and is for", but "few know that this technique is called Weierstrass substitution". So, to understand the question, for some it is better to simply make a guess, or even looking instead at the _answer_ below.

Comment: I should also mention that the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) talks about the geometry of this. The "motivation" for this substitution comes from wanting a rational parametrization of the unit circle

Answer (score 3):

It's used in converting functions like $f(\sin x,\cos x)$  into rational functions which have a established way to solve.

Stems from that,

$\sin x=\frac{2\tan{\frac{x}{2}}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}$

$\cos x=\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}$

So if there are other relations,we can use better substitution such as

1. $f(-\sin x,\cos x)=-f(\sin x,\cos x)$,let $t=\cos x$
2. $f(\sin x,-\cos x)=-f(\sin x,\cos x)$,let $t=\sin x$
3. $f(-\sin x,-\cos x)=f(\sin x,\cos x)$,let $t=\tan x$

Hope my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want a substitution to evaluate an integral $\int f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$, where $f$ is a rational function. You'll want your substitution to itself be a trig function and ideally all trigonometry goes away and you're left with algebra. One thing to observe is that $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ parametrizes the unit circle, whereas $x$ (in the usual $\mathrm{d}x$ integrals) tends to parametrize intervals on the real number line. This suggests something to investigate: what happens if you convert between these coordinates? The standard way to do this is with *stereographic projection*, although there are many ways to set up such a projection. Arguably the breeziest way to do this is by projecting onto the $y$-axis, since then the coordinate $t$ in the point $(0,t)$ is simply the slope of the line through the points $(-1,0),(0,t),(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. The inscribed angle theorem says this line makes an angle of $\theta/2$ with the $x$-axis, so $t=\tan(\theta/2)$. We can work out $\cos\theta,\sin\theta,\mathrm{d}\theta$ in terms of $t,\mathrm{d}t$ - fortuitously,

$$ \int f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta = \int f\Big(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\Big)\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}, $$

which means the Weierstrass substitution turns the integrand completely rational.

To investigate this substitution further, we can derive $\cos(\theta/2)$ and $\sin(\theta/2)$ in terms of $t$, which involves the radical $\sqrt{1+t^2}$. Then we can use the substitution to convert radical to trig integrand:

$$ f\big(t,\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\big)\,\mathrm{d}t= f\big(\tan(\theta/2),\sec(\theta/2)\big)\sec^2(\theta/2)\,\mathrm{d}(\theta/2)=g(\cos\psi,\sin\psi)\,\mathrm{d}\psi $$

We can do something similar with hyperbolic tangent and $\sqrt{1-t^2}$. By completing the square and using an affine transformation, this allows us to integrate $f(x,\sqrt{Q(x)})\,\mathrm{d}x$ for any quadratic $Q(x)$ and rational function $f$, though first we must simplify the numerator and denominator and rationalize to get it in the form $A(x)+B(x)/\sqrt{Q(x)}$ where $A$ and $B$ are rational functions.

Replacing $Q$ with a cubic (or even quadric) polynomial, we can use a substitution with the Weierstrass $\wp$ function, since $(\wp,\wp')$ parametrizes an elliptic curve.